# Suppress warnings sk* function

Tags: c, openssl

When using the libraries in the OpenSSL in a warning message:

```
warning: pointer type mismatch in conditional expression [enabled by default]
```

sample code:

```
X509_OBJECT *objs = sk_X509_OBJECT_value(st->objs, i);
...
sk_X509_OBJECT_free(objs); // this string generate error
```

I tried to change the type of a corresponding with source, but it did not help:

```
sk_X509_OBJECT_free( (_STACK*)objs );
sk_X509_OBJECT_free( (X509_OBJECT*)objs );
```

how to avoid it?

Answer (score 0):

First, here's what `sk_X509_OBJECT_free` is defined to:

```
$ grep -r -i sk_X509_OBJECT_free * | grep define
crypto/stack/safestack.h:#define sk_X509_OBJECT_free(st) SKM_sk_free(X509_OBJECT, (st))
```

And:

```
$ grep -r -i SKM_sk_free * | grep define
crypto/stack/safestack.h:#define SKM_sk_free(type, st) \
    sk_free(CHECKED_STACK_OF(type, st))
```

So `sk_free` is the underlying function:

```
$ grep -r -i "void sk_free" *
crypto/stack/stack.c:void sk_free(_STACK *st)
crypto/stack/stack.h:void sk_free(_STACK *);
doc/ssleay.txt:void sk_free(STACK *);
```

So casting to a `_STACK*` should fix the warning.

But I think a new warning was introduced with `CHECKED_SK_FREE_FUNC` (or `CHECKED_SK_FREE_FUNC2`) because it casts the function to a `void (*)` rather than providing its signature. They are shown below.

```
#define CHECKED_SK_FREE_FUNC(type, p) \
    ((void (*)(void *)) ((1 ? p : (void (*)(type *))0)))

#define CHECKED_SK_FREE_FUNC2(type, p) \
    ((void (*)(void *)) ((1 ? p : (void (*)(type))0)))
```

---

Also see [ternary operator with a constant (true) value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27586311/608639) if interested in the macros.

Comment: I changed the type to `_STASK*`or`STACK*` unfortunately, the error has not changed. Ternary operator - the right way, it is necessary to examine in relation to this issue.